# How to safely close stream when using threads

Tags: java, stream

I have thread with this code:

```
public void run() {

try {
    fileProcessor = new FileProcessor();
    fileProcessor.process();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    // ...
  } finally {
    if (fileProcessor != null) {
      fileProcessor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

method `fileProcessor.process();` run some new thread too:

```
protected void process() {
    this.writer = new Writer();
    final MyClient client = new MyClient();
    client.start();
}
```

this code sometimes thrown exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:26)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:99)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:116)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:203)
        at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
        at java.io.Writer.append(Writer.java:210)
```

how I can safely close stream? Because with `fileProcessor.close();` now probably I close this stream but there are still some thread which use it.

Comment: somewhat confused here.. That would close the respective thread fileProcessor. Can you plz post some more code that uses this or the inner code of this `run` method.

Comment: updated. I just want to close stream after all thread in fileProcessor are finished. I dont know this can helps me ?            synchronized (this) {
            fileProcessor.close();
          }

Comment: `Thread.join()` is the seems to be the answer here... as stated by invariant.

Comment: so this cant be done with synchronized ?

Answer (score 1):

use `thread.join()` for all threads in fileProcessor. so that it will wait until all threads finish their task.

```
client.start();
client.join(); // this will make sure client thread finished before proceed to next step
```

[Link to simple tutorial on thread.join for clear understanding](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/05/when-to-join-threads.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't start a new thread in your `process()` method, run the functionality synchronously instead.

Alternatively call your `close()` method from within your `process()` method.